# Multiple text color for UILabel text does not work in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift3, textcolor, nsmutableattributedstring

I tried to change the text color for the part of a `UILabel` like below.

```
func changetheColor () {
        let staticStrng : String = "Zave receipt"
        var mymutableAttributeString = NSMutableAttributedString()
        mymutableAttributeString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: staticStrng)

        mymutableAttributeString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location: 5,length: 7))
        saveReceiptLabel.text = mymutableAttributeString.string
    }
```

this doesn't work,What am I doing wrong. hope your help.

Comment: Replace last line with `saveReceiptLabel.attributedText = mymutableAttributeString`. It's the NSAttributedString that have the color (and possible other rendering effects) and the string, not the (NS)String which is just a chain of characters.

Comment: I tried, then it gives an error `cannot assign value of type NSMutableAttributedString of type String`

Comment: `saveReceiptLabel.attributedText =`, not `saveReceiptLabel.text =`, is that what you tried with my suggestion?

Comment: yep, got it. thats were I missed. thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this :

```
    saveReceiptLabel.attributedText = mymutableAttributeString.string
```

Comment: @AnuradhS: Does this code really works since at the end, it's `mymutableAttributeString.string` and not `mymutableAttributeString`?

Comment: @Larme yep , I already used it without `attributedText` part. in swift 3 it we use only `mymutableAttributeString` it will give you an error called ` cannot assign value of type NSMutableAttributedString of type String`

Comment: @AnuradhS I don't use Swift, but for me it's either `myLabel.text = myAttributedString.string` or `myLabel.attributedText = myAttributedString`, which won't have the same effect, but you shouldn't be able to mix them.

Comment: @Larme it woks fine for me, if I don't use `.string` it gives me an error.

Comment: Weird. It shouldn't. `saveReceiptLabel.attributedText = mymutableAttributeString.string` => "Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'NSAttributedString?'" and `saveReceiptLabel.text = mymutableAttributeString` => "Cannot assign value of type 'NSMutableAttributedString' to type 'String?'", which make sense.